# loading a UIWebView on second VC from another VC

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios6, uiwebview

I am trying to load a UIWebView located on a second VC before that VC is presented in order to reduce load time lag.

I have tried many different ways with not much luck.  I can get the webview to load and appear  if I load it directly from the 2nd VC, but there is a load lag. So, currently I am trying to pre-load the webview using -prepareForSegue method in the 1st VC.  The load occurs without any errors and the segue occurs as expected, but the webview is blank.

The webview on the 2nd VC is called QRWebView.

Here is the code from the first VC:

```
- (IBAction)btnQRWebView:(id)sender {

    [self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"segQRWebView" sender: self];
}



- (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"segQRWebView"])
{
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Terminologyapp" ofType:@"pdf"];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    QRWebViewController *qrview =segue.destinationViewController;
    [qrview.QRWebView loadRequest:request];

    }
}
```

The code from the 2nd VC simply sets the QRWebView.delegate to self in viewDidLoad method.  Any advice?

I've tried to make this work using delegate protocol but wasn't sure how to setup the QRWebView as a delegate.

Answer (score 1):

`UIWebView` will not render its content unless it is attached to a `UIWindow` instance.  The window to which it is attached does not need to be visible, however.  You could try attaching your webview to a window in `viewDidLoad` so that not only does it start loading its URL, but can start rendering content.  Then, in viewWillAppear, you can reattach it to its place inside your view controller's view.

That said, the time that it takes for your app to perform the segue and then show the view controller is so miniscule that this optimization may not improve your situation.

Comment: The real issue I'm having with lag shows up only on an iPad 3...because my segue is using a Partial Curl. The "curl" hangs for a second during the UIWebView load..making the animation jumpy.  I was trying to avoid that.  Everything works fine on an iPhone 5..mostly likely due to the faster processor.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating the webview and loading the request in your initial viewController.  Then pass that webView to your qrview.

```
UIWebView *webview = [UIWebView alloc] init]; // or initWithFrame or whatever
[webView loadRequest:request];
qrview.QRWebView = webView;
```

That may not be *exactly* right, but that's the basic idea.

Comment: AMayes..thanks, I did try that and got a blank webview after the segue.  I put your suggestion in the ViewDidLoad of the 1st VC (except for the last line, which stayed in the PrepareForSegue method).  It's like the 1st VC doesn't recognize the UIWebView setup on the 2nd VC.

Comment: Is QRWebView an instance, or a class?

Comment: QRWebView is an IBOutlet linked to a UIWebView object in the 2nd VC.

Answer (score 0):

Because QRWebView is an IBOutlet linked to a UIWebView object in 2nd VC, QRWebView would not load before the 2nd VC's view have been load. You can load the view manually in the prepare method.

```
QRWebViewController *qrview =segue.destinationViewController;
qrview.view;  // load the view
[qrview.QRWebView loadRequest:request];
```

Comment: Andraw...thanks, but I must be missing something.  The line qrview.view; gives a warning (propert access result unused).  Not sure I'm supposed to have additional code with that.